# Creating a .sh script to ADB Install a few APKs

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to make a script to install a few APKs using my Raspberry Pi. I can make a .bat that works fine on Windows, but I'm having an issue with Linux.

Here's my current script sample

```
#!/user/bin/X11 (location of where ADB is)
adb kill-server
adb remount
@ECHO Now installing 1
adb install /home/pi/Desktop/1.apk
@ECHO Now installing 2
adb install /home/pi/Desktop/2.apk
@ECHO Now installing 3
adb install /home/pi/Desktop/3.apk
pause
```

When I run the script, terminal pops up but does nothing. I did use chmod a+x on the .sh file.

Updated on the script with BASH syntax. Same issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
adb kill-server
adb remount
echo "Now installing 1"
adb install /home/pi/Desktop/1.apk
echo "Now installing 2"
adb install /home/pi/Desktop/2.apk
echo "Now installing 3"
adb install /home/pi/Desktop/3.apk
read
```

Comment: Yeah, because that's batch syntax. You need to use BASH syntax.

Comment: I'm still learning Linux. I adjusted with the Bash syntax. Same issue. I'll update my post with the new adjustment.

Comment: Are you actually using `#1` or is that a typo? You should also run scripts by executing them from a terminal that's already running.

Comment: 1. Are you using Raspbian or another OS?
2. Where is your adb and how did you install it?
Try typing which adb in a terminal. This may be a PATH issue

Comment: #1 was a typo. I'm trying to make this a double click the script and it'll perform the commands. I'm using Raspbian. ADB was installed via terminal. 

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot

If I open terminal and type adb install /path/1.apk, it'll install the apk fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below command for install few apks at once:

> adb install-multiple